# Creating a Secure iPhone Web Data Source

Tags: iphone, mysql, security

I've searched the web for this bit to no avail - I Hope some one can point me in the right direction.  I'm happy to look things up, but its knowing where to start.

I am creating an iPhone app which takes content updates from a webserver and will also push feedback there.  Whilst the content is obviously available via the app, I don't want the source address to be discovered and published my some unhelpful person so that it all becomes freely available.

I'm therefore looking at placing it in a mySQL database and possibly writing some PHP routines to provide access to my http(s) requests.  That's all pretty new to me but I can probably do it.  However, I'm not sure where to start with the security question.  Something simple and straightforward would be great.  Also, any guidance on whether to stick with the XML parser I currently have or to switch to JSON would be much appreciated.

The content consists of straightforward data but also html and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want (prevent users from 'unauthorized' apps to get access to this data') is rather difficult because at the end of the day, any access codes and/or URLs will be stored in your app for someone to dig up and exploit.

If you can, consider authenticating against the USER not the App.  So that even if there is a 3rd party app created that can access this data from where ever you store it, you can still disable it on a per-user basis.

Like everything in the field of Information Security, you have to consider the cost-benefit.  You need to weigh-up the value of your data vs. the cost of your security both in terms of actual development cost and the cost of protecting it as well as the cost of inconveniencing users to the point that you can't sell your data at all.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Mkoistinen.  Sorry for not getting back to you earlier.  I'm using HTTPs now.  I understand the risk/ reward equation with security.  Is it possible for someone to reverse engineer the bundle that is sent to a device?  i.e. first of all is it possible to get hold of it and secondly, if you can, can you then see the code (i.e. the URLs) it uses?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using HTTPS, most people will probably struggle to intercept your 'bundle' in transit. However, the urls would still appear in the network packets and will appear in logs, be considered by firewall rules, etc. Also, the urls would be stored in your app, so anyone with access to the application binaries, should be able to obtain them.  Even if you attempt to encrypt these urls in your app, someone could reverse-engineer your code to obtain them.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mkoistinen, so I think what you're saying is that I can't hide the URL including the parameters, no matter what I do.  I thought the whole point of https was to do that.